# unable to create javafx application .deb package for linux

Tags: javafx

```
[fx:deploy] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "fakeroot" (in directory "/tmp/fxbundler2581933641178636333/images/linux-deb.image"): error=2, No such file or directory
[fx:deploy]     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
[fx:deploy]     at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:146)
[fx:deploy]     at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:138)
[fx:deploy]     at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:132)
[fx:deploy]     at com.oracle.tools.packager.linux.LinuxDebBundler.buildDeb(LinuxDebBundler.java:846)
[fx:deploy]     at com.oracle.tools.packager.linux.LinuxDebBundler.bundle(LinuxDebBundler.java:352)
[fx:deploy]     at com.oracle.tools.packager.linux.LinuxDebBundler.execute(LinuxDebBundler.java:898)
[fx:deploy]     at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:506)
[fx:deploy]     at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:471)
[fx:deploy]     at com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask.execute(DeployFXTask.java:285)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
[fx:deploy]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
[fx:deploy]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[fx:deploy]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[fx:deploy]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
[fx:deploy]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:452)
[fx:deploy]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:139)
[fx:deploy] Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
[fx:deploy]     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
[fx:deploy]     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
[fx:deploy]     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
[fx:deploy]     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
[fx:deploy]     ... 24 more

BUILD FAILED
/home/india/Desktop/ReadEdge/build/build.xml:208: Error: Bundler "DEB Installer" (deb) failed to produce a bundle.

Total time: 54 seconds
```

Answer (score 14):

The error message is a bit misleading in its talk of "no such file or directory" so that, at first sight, it sounds as though there's something missing from the `tmp` directory.

What it's *actually* complaining about is the fact that `fakeroot` is not installed on your system. Assuming you're building on an ubuntu-like system, this should sort you out:

```
sudo apt-get install fakeroot
```

`fakeroot` was a new one on me. [This link explains why you need it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9714/what-is-the-need-for-fakeroot-command-in-linux).

Comment: Eh? The OP got an exception trying to build a JavaFX app. I got the same exception, then found that installing fakeroot fixed it. The answer is to install fakeroot. There's no question in there.

Comment: @GuillaumeFache also the first line of error log in question mentiones the `fakeroot` command.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to jonnyp's answer regarding `fakeroot` since I just came across the same problem as the OP when trying to package a Scala Play application.

On Mac OS, you can install `fakeroot` with Homebrew:

```
brew install fakeroot
```

To create a Debian package on my Mac, I then also needed to install the Debian package management module using `brew install dpkg`. Might save someone a search if this is the first page they come across!