# Ant build fails on linux machine

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, ant

I am trying to set up jenkins build server for one of minor projects in my company. Earlier builds were made by chosen developer on windows machine by hand. Ant build is working OK on windows, but on linux machine (jenkins/jenkins:latest docker image) it is not working. Below is step where build fails :

```
    <mkdir dir="deploy" />
    <fx:deploy
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="false"
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
        outfile="FILENAME" nativeBundles="all"
        updatemode="background" >

        <fx:platform basedir="${JAVA_HOME}"/>
        <fx:info title="APPNAME" vendor="PCOMPANYNAME"/>

        <fx:application refId="fxApplication" />
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    </fx:deploy>
```

And here is the output from jenkins console:

```
Do-Deploy:
 [echo] ::START:: Deployment process
[mkdir] Created dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/XXX/build/dist
[mkdir] Created dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/XXX/build/dist/libs
 [copy] Copying 32 files to /var/jenkins_home/workspace/XXX/build/dist
[mkdir] Created dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/XXX/build/build/classes/META-INF
[mkdir] Created dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/XXX/build/deploy
Using base JDK at: /docker-java-home/jre

Using base JDK at: /docker-java-home/jre
Creating app bundle: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/XXX/build/deploy/bundles/XXX
Debian packages should specify a license.  The absence of a license will cause some linux distributions to complain about the quality of the application.

[fx:deploy] java.io.IOException: Exec failed with code 2 command [[fakeroot, dpkg-deb, -b, XXX, /var/jenkins_home/workspace/XXX/build/deploy/bundles/XXX.deb] in /tmp/fxbundler6370267168449686200/images/linux-deb.image
[fx:deploy]     at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:165)
[fx:deploy]     at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:138)
[fx:deploy]     at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:132)
[fx:deploy]     at com.oracle.tools.packager.linux.LinuxDebBundler.buildDeb(LinuxDebBundler.java:871)
[fx:deploy]     at com.oracle.tools.packager.linux.LinuxDebBundler.bundle(LinuxDebBundler.java:363)
[fx:deploy]     at com.oracle.tools.packager.linux.LinuxDebBundler.execute(LinuxDebBundler.java:923)
[fx:deploy]     at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:352)
[fx:deploy]     at com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:319)
[fx:deploy]     at com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask.execute(DeployFXTask.java:286)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
[fx:deploy]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
[fx:deploy]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[fx:deploy]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:857)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:287)
[fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:113)

BUILD FAILED
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/XXX/build/build.xml:163: Error: Bundler "DEB Installer" (deb) failed to produce a bundle.
```

Same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 VM. I am lost what may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

so I found a similar topic on SO. It also concerns Ubuntu and the log file also states that the case might be the `fakeroot`

try adding this to dockerfile
`apt-get install fakeroot`

The topic I am talking about:
[unable to create javafx application .deb package for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968203/unable-to-create-javafx-application-deb-package-for-linux#31335495)

Comment: Yes, i've seen that, but fakeroot is installed : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven openjfx fakeroot zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev lib32z1 lib32ncurses5

Comment: can you share the dockerfile?

Comment: yeah, it is very simple one. FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y maven openjfx fakeroot zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev lib32z1 lib32ncurses5
ADD launch4j /launch4j